JDBC connector for docker compose
I've been trying to setup the MySQL JDBC connector following the instructions i found here but I'm afraid I'm still having issues with my setup.
I'm using a docker-compose with image version ontotext/graphdb:9.11.1-se and according to the documentation of this version the file goes into lib/. I saw newer versions can use /lib/jdbc which makes it easier for me to use a volume in my docker-compose file.
B
I also tried modifying the options:

Dgraphdb.ontop.jdbc.path=/opt/graphdb/home/lib/jdbc
modifying the graphdb.properties file with graphdb.ontop.jdbc.path = /opt/graphdb/home/lib/jdbc
but with no positive results.

At the moment I tried with ontotext/graphdb:10.6.3 and the lib/jdbc path works, any suggestions or ideas?

Can you try mounting your jars at /opt/graphdb/dist/lib/jdbc and without providing any extra configuration properties?
